# how can i make the last <div> green?

Tags: html, css

I'm really new to HTML and CSS and I have just studied nesting where I've got an issue with one of the css challenges for beginners.
Here are the challenge requirements:

1. to make the word (title) red.
2. to make the word (child title) blue.
3. to make the word (paragraph content) green.
4. to make the word (section title) green too.

I was already gives the HTML code and as per the requirements I MUST NOT make any change in it.

```css
div div span {
  color: red;
}

div span {
  color: blue;
}

p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">This Is Child <span class="title">Title</span></div>
  <span class="title">Child Title</span>
  <p>Paragraph Content</p>
</div>
<div class="title">Section Title</div>
```

Kindly assist with number 4. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: use pseudo selector last child

Comment: `:nth-last-child` or `:nth-last-of-type` selector

Comment: There are classes in the HTML you provided, so why don’t you use them in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can take note of this CSS for all requirements.

`>` = child selector

`~` = sibling selector

`,` = comma represents styles for both elements separately

```css
.parent>.child>span {
  color: red;
}

.parent>.child~.title {
  color: blue;
}

.parent>p,
.title {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">This Is Child <span class="title">Title</span></div>
  <span class="title">Child Title</span>
  <p>Paragraph Content</p>
</div>
<div class="title">Section Title</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works indeed! I just don't get why the last (.title) worked although there are a lot of elements with the same class?!

Comment: @simokitkat Because I used the child selector `>` to target the first `.title` span class which is a child to `.child`. I used a sibling selector `~` for the span not nested in the child. That means only an element with a class called `.title`. that is a sibling to `.child` will get the color blue. - The `div` with `.title` is not a child to `.parent` nor a `sibling` to `child`, therefore it knows what I am talking about just with writing `.title`. If anything, the div with `.title` is a sibling to `.parent` so you could use `.parent~.title` to also target the last div. Hope that was clear.

Comment: If you want, I can post the same result without using any class names, which may help you understand more how the selectors work.

Answer (score -1):

Change your CSS to

```css
div div span { 
color: red;
}
div span { 
color: blue;
}
p { 
color: green;
}div {
color: green;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).